# Converting float to int in F#

Tags: f#

Can someone please explain why `int (0.4 * 10.0)` is `4` yet `int ((2.4 - 2.0) * 10.0)` is `3`?

And then also please explain how to get `4`.  i.e. Do I really have to do `int (System.Math.Round((2.4 - 2.0) * 10.0))`?

It's just so ugly for something that should be so simple.

Comment: It should be noted that this is not an F# specific "issue", but rather in the nature of most languages, at least all of .NET.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The double representation of 2.4 - 2.0 is 0.399999999999. When you convert a number to int the decimal part is truncated so 3.999999999 is truncated to 3.

Comment: That's correct, if you want to get 4.0 then you can use Math.Round:

Math.Round((2.4 - 2.0) * 10.0)

Answer (score 6):

Actually, in .Net there is a `decimal` data type which will help you with this problem, if your numbers can be represented exactly as decimal fractions.

```
2.4m - 2.0m == 0.4m
2.4 - 2.0   != 0.4
```

Answer (score 6):

To covert a `float` number to an `int` use:

`let i = Convert.ToInt32(f)`

Comment: Just a note for new users (like me): needs `open System` first

Comment: So, without importing any reference it is like this:

```let i = System.Convert.ToInt32(f)```

Answer (score 5):

> And then also please explain how to get 4. i.e. Do I really have to do
>
> int (System.Math.Round((2.4 - 2.0) * 10.0))
>
> it's just so ugly for something that should be so simple.

Of course not, just define

```
let round x = int System.Math.Round(x)
```

Comment: This is not compiling. I get the error: Successive arguments should be separated by spaces or tupled, and arguments involving function or method applications should be parenthesized

Answer (score 1):

Floating-point numbers are not infinite precision.  Some numbers can be represented perfectly (anything involving powers of two, e.g. 1, 1/2 = 0.5, 1/4 = 0.25, etc.), and others can't (e.g. 1/3 cannot be exactly decomposed into a finite sequence of powers of two).  Often, chopping the end of the infinite series causes the encoded version of a number to be slightly smaller than its true value.

Combine this with the fact that the (int) operator truncates rather than rounds, and you can run into cases where an operation that *should* yield 4.0 results in 3.999999999991 instead, which becomes 3.

Any time you're trying to convert floats/doubles to ints, you want to think carefully about which operator you want to use -- truncating (rounding down), rounding up, or rounding-to-nearest.

Since this is an issue with floating-point representations, this is true not just in F#, but C# and (IIRC) Java and other languages.